# How to deal with Excel popup when using Workbooks.OpenXML

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I'm trying to use vbs to open XML via Excel.

Below is my code:

```vb
Set myxl = createobject("excel.application")
myxl.DisplayAlerts = False
myxl.Application.Visible = true
myxl.Workbooks.OpenXML "SampleXML.XML",1,xlXmlLoadImportToList
```

But when code runs, Excel will pop up an option to ask how to open this file.
I'm sorry that I don't have enough reputation to post images. This popup will ask you whether open XML as "As an XML table" (which I want, but I don't want popup), "As a read-only workbook", "Use the XML Source task pane".

How do I aviod this pop up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `xlXmlLoadImportToList`. It is an Excel Constant and not a VBScript Constant. It has a value `2`. You can check that in the `Immediate` window of Excel as shown below.

[image]

Try this :)

```
Const xlXmlLoadImportToList = 2
Set myxl = createobject("excel.application")
myxl.DisplayAlerts = False
myxl.Application.Visible = true
myxl.Workbooks.OpenXML "C:\Test.XML",1,xlXmlLoadImportToList
```

Comment: Glad to be of help :)